# Linked library vs. standalone contract

Tags: solidity, gas, solidity-0.8.x, library

What is the benefit of a linked library over a standalone contract? Let's say I want to reuse code between multiple contracts. The code itself has no state.

Example library:

```typescript
library SafeMath {
  function add(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) external pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = _a + _b;
      require(c >= _a, "ERROR_ADD_OVERFLOW");
      return c;
  }
}

contract UsingLibrary {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  uint256 x = 0;

  function doSomething() public {
    x = x.add(1);
  }
}
```

Example external contract

```typescript
contract SafeMath {
  function add(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) external pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = _a + _b;
      require(c >= _a, "ERROR_ADD_OVERFLOW");
      return c;
  }
}

contract UsingExternalContract {
  SafeMath private constant math = 0x123abc...;
 
  uint256 x = 0;

  function doSomething() public {
    x = math.add(x, 1);
  }
}
```

Is there some difference in terms of gas costs? Both `call` and `delegatecall` cost the same amount of gas and if the destination address of the `SafeMath` contract is stored in a `constant` variable, there isn't any gas cost to read the address of the library contract. What are reasons one should use an external (linked) library over a separate contract that effectively does the same?

Comment: Maybe not the answer that u are looking for, but I think it is a programming philosophy and you need to deploy 2 contracts instead of one. In other cases you don’t want to rely on another external contract for security issues even if it is controlled by you.

Comment: well in both cases you need to deploy 2 times. In the first case a library and a contract and in the second case two contracts. I'm not talking about embedded libraries, only linked libraries

Answer (score 1):

**Gas used**

```
With Library:
SafeMath = 118864 gas
UsingLibrary = 111831 gas
```

**Total = 230695 gas**

```
With External Contract:
SafeMath = 116299 gas
UsingExternalContract = 111831 gas
```

**Total = 228130 gas**

Conclusion: **External Contract** is better to save gas.

Tested in Remix with Solidity compiler version 0.8.17.